# Which mounting screws to use for Ikea Hoppvals?

Tags: screws, mounting, blinds

I recently bought these Ikea blinds ([HOPPVALS](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/hoppvals-room-darkening-cellular-blind-grey-10386431/)).
To my surprise when I opened the package there was no mounting screws to use or any recommendation of what kind of screws would be the appropriate ones to use.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Did they include the mounting brackets ? Did you inspect all the packaging, small parts can get overlooked and tossed out.

Comment: @AlaskaMan From the manual (online): **As wall materials vary, screws for fixing
to wall are not included. For advice on suitable screw systems, contact your local
specialised dealer.** Which in normal times might mean: Ask one of the IKEA employees at the store. But now means: Ask some random people on the internet.

Comment: As the manual indicates, we can't guess without knowing the wall (or window frame or ceiling or whatever) material. Wood? Drywall over a hollow space? Drywall right on top of wood? Concrete?

Comment: We need to know what type of wall or window frame are you attaching these blinds to.  A picture of where you are installing these blinds would help.

Answer (score 1):

There is much info  on how to mount blinds on the internet.

This type of blind USUALLY  mount inside the window casing ,to the top of the window casing which is typically wood. If so then 1"  wood screws would be sufficient to deal with the weight of of the blinds and the mechanical forces of pulling them down.

BUT the photo on the IKEA site seams to indicate that the bracket is mounted to the wall, If this is how you will be mounting them ( *and your wall is made of drywall* ) then you you need to know if there is structure in the wall at the mounting location. If there is structure, stud or header etc,  then any good wood screw ( *at least 1 1/4"* ) will work. If not you will need a toggle anchor to deal with the forces involved.

**I prefer [Toggler](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0051IAQN2) anchors.**

As manassehkatz says, you need to know what your wall is made of in order to know how to proceed.

Comment: The pictures look to me like they mount inside the window casing and attach to the top. I'd agree that a 1" wood screw should do just fine. If the OP has children or pets that might play with/paw at the blinds, a longer screw (2-3") could be used to anchor into the header above the window for added security, however it's really not necessary. Unless, of course, it's a masonry wall in which case a toggle bolt of some sort would be necessary for a longer screw - just stick with a short one.